# MobileFirst 6.3: Could not find method org.json.JSONException.<init>

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

IBM MobileFirst 6.3.0 in Windows

I have few warning and exceptions when I work with Json Store.

Can that be ignored or any fix is available, Since I am using latest MobileFirst studio installed from Eclipse Market place

**JSON STORE Code:**

```
var jsonStoreObject = { };

jsonStoreObject.collectionName = 'people';

jsonStoreObject.collections = {
            people : {
                searchFields : {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
            }
};  

jsonStoreObject.options = {
            username : "Hello",
            password : "123"
};


function openJSON(){
WL.JSONStore.init(jsonStoreObject.collections, jsonStoreObject.options)
.then(function(data) {          
    WL.Logger.info("After Init::"+ JSON.stringify(data));
    return WL.JSONStore.get(jsonStoreObject.collectionName).findAll();
})  
.then(function(findAllResult) {
    WL.Logger.info("findAllResult::"+ JSON.stringify(findAllResult));
    if (findAllResult.length == 0) {
        var data = [{name: 'carlos', age: 10}];
        return WL.JSONStore.get(jsonStoreObject.collectionName).add(data);
    }
})
.fail(function (errorObject) {
    console.log("Json Failure:: " + WL.JSONStore.getErrorMessage(errorObject));
});
}
```

Exceptions/Warnings:

> 03-18 05:23:17.332: I/dalvikvm(1669): Could not find method
> org.json.JSONException., referenced from method
> com.worklight.androidgap.jsonstore.security.DPKBean.
>
> 03-18 05:23:17.332: W/dalvikvm(1669): VFY: unable to resolve direct method
> 34098: Lorg/json/JSONException;. (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

Also, when I call the openJSON() for the first time I used to get following log like database already exists.

> 03-18 06:50:05.518: D/JSONSTORE(1053): JSONStoreLogger.logDebug in
> JSONStoreLogger.java:174 :: provisioning database "people" (already
> exists: false)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is just a warning, and it always shows up. It does not affect anything. The second one is just a debug message telling you if the collection you are creating was previously created or not; if it had already existed, it would just return that one, and say "already exists:true".

Neither of them affect the execution, so you don't have to worry about them.